# How can I put in security so that my server only accepts requests coming from my app

Tags: java, android, security, oauth-2.0

I have an app and a server side service which my app communicates with with JSON.

I need to impliment security so that if someone gets hold of the urls they will only be able to just call them.

I know i need to use Oauth2 but I don't know how to exactly.

I have read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html#ConnectToService) and it seems to be what I want but it's using google accounts.

Can anyone give me an example or steps I must take to make sure only my app is able to get a response from my server?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `accesstoken` for each http request.It can be just a string.

Comment: the accesstoken will be visible if someone snoops on the communications the app is making. therefore tsomeone can fgind the url containing the accesstoken and use that no?

Comment: No you should keep your `accessToken` private.Also you can encrypt the `accessToken` when making `httpRequests` and at server side decrypt it.

Comment: Anyone intercepting the request will see the encrypted key and use that because server will decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, if you want to use `oauth/oauth2`, you should implement your oauth server. And if you really want to do so, you could find some opensource project. But in a simple way, just add a app code(like the accesstoken, anything just used to identify your app) manually to each http request. in this way, if others know your app code, they are also able to send request to your server.

Comment: but how do i stop others from making requests even if they manage to find my accesstoken

Comment: As i know, if others get your accesstoken they could do request even you use oauth2. So you'd better keep you token safely, or add some other condition to verify the request, like signature etc.